# Is there any method to play a sound from a PHP image file?

Tags: php, html, image, audio

I have tried many times and failed, but I will show an example code anyway.

```
<?php
Header ('Content-type: image/png');
Header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
Header('Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT');
Header('Pragma: no-cache');
// create the image
$image = imagecreatefrompng("PrivateImage.png");
// output and destroy
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

I have taken my image-creator's source code and compiled it down to be really simple in basic terms of what I am doing.

I am creating a custom image from about 4 sources and the image creation works flawlessly and outputs flawlessly.  I would like to be able to incur a script event client side when the image is loaded and play a sound file that is off of my server. (Each time the image is loaded)

Mainly this is a pet project of mine to make a really unique forum sig that plays a short tune when the page is loaded, and no, "media" is not "allowed" in the fourm sig.  I was challenged with trying to get to a point where it plays a sound in your browser when it loads and posting this means I failed.  I have tried using the

`readfile("/path/to/file");`

to read an html file that already has a working audio player module. However, that does not load at all. Picture still shows though.

I have also tried to escape php with

```
<?php
{
?>
<embed src="sound.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false" style="width:5px; height:2px;">
<?php
}
?>
```

This is also a no-result that does not affect the image output at all but also does not play.  However loading it as it's own php resource works fine for me. (Separate page.)

If playing sounds while the content tag is set to `image/png` is not possible just say so. However with the internet anything is possible... to an extent. I figured it would not hurt to at least ask.  Anything I've found close to this issue / question is far too old to be relied on.

Comment: No. Image files cannot typically mix in audio/ content. Appending trailing HTML (=garbage data) to a PNG won't work either.

Comment: I was afraid of that. And thanks to bencripps for the suggested editing of this. This was the first question I couldn't quite get a solid answer out of with a few hours of research.